# open sublink in the same page with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In html i am having the page created like following

```
2012-2013
  a
  b
```

2011-2012

```
  a
  b
```

in which 2012-2013 are the main link on clicking 2012 and 2013 sub link a and b should 
   be opened while clicking on the link  again a and b sublink should be hidden 
   i want to use javascript for it

Comment: You really need to learn some punctuation, man. I tried to read the question like 3 times and yet i cannot understand a single s~t.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this. Its html5. Only chrome supports it for now:

```
<details>
<summary>2012-2013</summary>
<p> a b</p>
</details>
<details>
<summary>2011-2012</summary>
<p> c d </p>
</details>
```